# Record and playback sound simultaneously using external mic as input and bluetooth/earphones as output in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I am developing an app where we have the following objective:

- Record a sound from an external microphone while it's being played simultaneously on an external earphones/bluetooth device.

I have read many posts about how to achieve this and I didn't find the way to do it. Many opinions and guesses but any reference project or clear instructions to achieve this. `AVCaptureSession`, `AVAudioEngine`, `AVAudiosession`, or `RemoteIO` have been put forward to achieve it. After a lot of reading, was looking for some light on this topic.

- Does anyone know any reference project, guide, or way to achieve this?
- Doesn't `AVaudiosession` provide this option with `AVaudiorecorder` and `AVaudioplayer`?

Comment: please visit link and check if it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815387/how-to-record-video-and-play-audio-at-the-same-time-swift-tutorial

Comment: See Help Center to find out what type of questions are acceptable here.

Comment: @Sumit_VE thank you for your answer. He have checked this link before, but there is an important difference. In that case, the playing video and the recorded audio do not correspond to the same file. In our case, we want to record and play simultaneously the input sound (at the moment of playing the audio, the recorded file does not exist).